# How to check is session exists in all controller in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to check session in all request and if specific session not exist redirect user to login page.

I use `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ModelAttribute` together to check session before every request but if session is not exist how to redirect user?

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = "ir.sadeghpro.magnet.controller")
public class Advice {

    @ModelAttribute
    public void checkSession(HttpSession session){
    if (session.getAttribute("user") == null){
        System.out.println("session is not exists");
        // how to redirect user
    }
}
```

The second way is using `HandlerInterceptor` to get request before send to controller

```
@Component
public class CheckSessionInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if (session == null || session.getAttribute("user") == null) {
            String url = request.getHeader("x-forwarded-proto") + "://" + request.getHeader("x-forwarded-host") + "/login";
            response.sendRedirect(url);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

but in this way static resource like js or css or image will be redirect to `/login` url

is there any way to check session or any condition and if return false redirect to some page for all request not check that in each controller?

Comment: Do you have Spring Security on the classpath?

Comment: sry I don't use spring security can you explain more how to use it

Comment: Explaining how to use Spring Security is a little beyond the scope of what we do here, but there are plenty of tutorials available. However, it will do what you want our of the box.

Comment: tnx for your time. I test it